# How to install GimpShop on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to install GimpShop for Ubuntu 16.04 from its official site, www.gimpshop.com

where there are supposed to be different download links for each platform. But the Debian packages link redirects to the regular Gimp. I also tried to follow [Suramya's](http://linux.suramya.com/tutorials/Install_GIMPShop/) guide, but still the download link is broken. Does anyone know a way to install it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note to answerers - the GIMPShop site only offers an Adware installer for the actual GIMP, don't try to download anything from there to answer this question!

Comment: @Zanna, don't know protocol here; wouldn't it be better to edit the link out of the question than to leave it on the first line and hope future readers get to your comment before they click?

Comment: yeah I think so - I have removed the active link

Answer (score 39, accepted):

GIMPShop is not a thing. The actual GIMPShop project (a fork of GIMP aiming to be similar to Photoshop) was abandoned ~2006. There are some old & untrustworthy tarballs/.deb packages floating around but I checked one out recently and it was completely broken.

That site you link to is basically a scam. They offer an installer that downloads the normal GIMP from the official sources but is also some kind of adware. As their site even admits:

> Gimpshop.com is distributing the original unmodified software,
> obtained directly from GIMP's repository website, and does not modify
> it in any way. These installers comply with the original software
> manufacturer's policies and terms & conditions. DownloadAdmin™ is an
> install manager, which manages the installation of your chosen
> software. In addition to managing your download and installation,
> DownloadAdmin™ will offer free popular software that you may be
> interested in. You are not required to install any additional software
> to complete your installation of your selected software.

I asked a [question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/distributor-tcs-appear-to-conflict-with-gpl-is-this-a-violation) about this on Open Source SE, and I believe the site is violating the GPL license of GIMP.

@edwinksl also pointed me to [this relevant post](http://www.gimp.org/news/2014/12/26/the-price-of-being-popular/) and some bad reviews of the site [here](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/www.gimpshop.com)

## **Do not attempt to download anything from the GIMPSHOP site**

Install gimp safely from repositories:

```
sudo apt install gimp
```

Comment: Thanks Zanna, your answer is very helpful and spared me time to dig for it.

Comment: You're most welcome and thank you for asking, I think this question will help others @youta

Comment: It was abandoned in 2005-2006.

Comment: Also worth noting that although it was abandoned, the changes have mostly been folded into trunk GIMP—primarily "Windows → Single-Window Mode," which you should totally enable. (Not sure about the causality here; I seem to recall the project being abandoned before the changes were merged, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: @wchargin that's not the changes of gimpshop, single-window mode is the gimp project's own achievement

Comment: Well, okay, perhaps the implementation is different. But IIRC it was one of GIMPShop's primary features as well.