# How to create a minimalist cartoon avatar using linux?

Tags: software-installation, gimp, image-processing, photoshop, image-editor

Is there any way we can make a minimalistic cartoon avatar of our photo using softwares available for linux. On Windows it can be created using photoshop. But i don't know how to create the same using softwares available for linux. I know there are softwares like gimp available for this platform but I have a very little knowledge about them. 
p.s. if you dont know what a minimalistic cartoon avatar or vector avatar is you can find it on marques brownlee's profile (mkbhd) on YouTube.

Comment: It's really vector, I think you could try out Inkscape, (`sudo apt install inkscape`). Then import your image, and in the menu use Path->Trace Bitmap...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know there are softwares like gimp available for this platform but I have a very little knowledge about them.

So do `apt-get -y install gimp` and try it out! It's not very hard to make a "minimalistic cartoon avatar" in `gimp`. I don't think there is a FOSS tool that just takes a photo `.jpg` and spits out a "minimalistic cartoon avatar" automatically.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, there is also gimpshop for an addon which mimics photoshop layout.  It helps with familiarity, imho.

Comment: @bc2946088 I will be impressed when photoshop has an addon to mimic gimp layout :)

Comment: @bc2946088 I just did a bit of Googling on gimpshop and this is what I found: http://askubuntu.com/a/821985/339837. Not impressive if you ask me...

Comment: Fair enough, @shyam.  I used it many years ago, and I found it very usable and had a good likeness to Photoshop 6.  As the link you found, the project has been abandoned, I was unaware.  Time flies.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I personally suggest [Krita](https://krita.org). It's powerful, easy to use for beginners, and the interface will be somewhat familiar for Photoshop users. I strongly suggest getting the latest version via their [download page](https://krita.org/en/download/krita-desktop/), since it has numerous improvements over the versions available in the Ubuntu repositories. It's distributed in AppImage format too, so it's easy to remove if you decide you don't want it.

Also note that it is possible to install Photoshop on Linux by installing the `playonlinux` package and using that. However, it's not likely to be as reliable as native software and you can't expect support if it doesn't work. (Source: myself; I've written several scripts for PlayOnLinux.)